# Scaling a tikzpicture for a Beamer slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have the following Beamer slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex    ]
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Simulated Annealing (SA)}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
            \node[block]                  (init){Init $n=0$, $T_0$, and $S_0$};
            \node[block, below of=init]   (nbrh){$S_{n+1}=N(S_n)$};
            \node[decision, below of=nbrh](ovgt){$f(S_{n+1}) \le f(S_n)$};
            \node[block, below of=ovgt]   (accp){Accept $S_{n+1}$};
            \node[decision, right of=ovgt](rand){$e^{-\frac{\Delta f}{t_n}}$};
            \node[block, right of=nbrh]   (rejj){Reject $S_{n+1}$};
            \node[block, below of=accp]   (incr){$T_{n+1} = K(T_n)$ and $n++$};
            \node[block, below of=incr]   (stop){Stop};
            \node[decision, left of=stop] (stcd){Stop?};

            \path[line] (init) --          (nbrh);
            \path[line] (nbrh) --          (ovgt);
            \path[line] (ovgt) -- node{yes}(accp);
            \path[line] (ovgt) -- node{no} (rand);
            \path[line] (rand) -- node{no} (rejj);
            \path[line] (rejj) --          (nbrh);
            \path[line] (rand) |- node{yes}(accp);
            \path[line] (accp) -|          (stcd);
            \path[line] (stcd) -- node{yes}(stop);
            \path[line] (stcd) |- node{no} (nbrh);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and I got the code mostly from [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/).

The only problem is that it doesn't fit in the beamer slide. It isn't auto scaled, and it runs way off the bottom.

I have tried adding `scale = 0.25` to the `\begin{tikzpicture}[]` but that didn't do anything at all.

Is there any way to auto-fit the whole tikzpicture into the available space in my frame?

[image]

Bonus question: Why is Reject S_{n+1} not horizontally aligned with the exponential decision underneath, and as such - why is the arrow connecting them at an angle? (i.e., how is this fixed?)

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: You could try `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill That makes it even wider, and hence taller. Without the `\resizebox` the width is only about 75% the width of the slide.

Comment: Sorry, I had assumed that your image was too wide when I posted that comment.

Answer (score 47):

Using `scale = 0.25` to the `\begin{tikzpicture}[]` only scales coordinates, but not node sizes. For complex things like `tikzpicture`s I recommend my `adjustbox` package.
Here you can specify the maximal size, e.g. in factors of the text width and height.
Note that the text height also includes the head line. You can add the `center` key to horizontally center it without adding vertical space before and after like with the `center` environment:

```
% Preamble:
\usepackage{adjustbox}

% Body:

\begin{frame}
\begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={.9\textwidth}{.7\textheight},center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[..]
 ..
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}
```

See the `adjustbox` manual for more keys and other details.

Comment: This even works for fragile frames with verbatim inside the tikzpicture.

Comment: @John: yes, `adjustbox` boxes the content and therefor supports verbatim content.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `\resizebox{5.0cm}{!}{}` to resize the image, and specifying and anchor point fixes the problem with the `Reject $S_{n+1}$`:

```
\node[block, right of=nbrh, anchor=west]   (rejj){Reject $S_{n+1}$};
```

Similarly to fix the issue with `Accept $S_{n+1}$`, use

```
\node[block, below of=ovgt, anchor=north]   (accp){Accept $S_{n+1}$};
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex    ]
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Simulated Annealing (SA)}
    \begin{center}
\resizebox{5.0cm}{!}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
            \node[block]                  (init){Init $n=0$, $T_0$, and $S_0$};
            \node[block, below of=init]   (nbrh){$S_{n+1}=N(S_n)$};
            \node[decision, below of=nbrh](ovgt){$f(S_{n+1}) \le f(S_n)$};
            \node[block, below of=ovgt, anchor=north]   (accp){Accept $S_{n+1}$};
            \node[decision, right of=ovgt](rand){$e^{-\frac{\Delta f}{t_n}}$};
            \node[block, right of=nbrh, anchor=west]   (rejj){Reject $S_{n+1}$};
            \node[block, below of=accp]   (incr){$T_{n+1} = K(T_n)$ and $n++$};
            \node[block, below of=incr]   (stop){Stop};
            \node[decision, left of=stop] (stcd){Stop?};

            \path[line] (init) --          (nbrh);
            \path[line] (nbrh) --          (ovgt);
            \path[line] (ovgt) -- node{yes}(accp);
            \path[line] (ovgt) -- node{no} (rand);
            \path[line] (rand) -- node{no} (rejj);
            \path[line] (rejj) --          (nbrh);
            \path[line] (rand) |- node{yes}(accp);
            \path[line] (accp) -|          (stcd);
            \path[line] (stcd) -- node{yes}(stop);
            \path[line] (stcd) |- node{no} (nbrh);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        }%
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The "no" line going up to the reject box isn't quite vertical :( I'm also about to start another question about the overlapped flow line from "Stop?" to "S_{n+1}".

Comment: +1 did you try using `scale=<number>` where `<number>` is less than 1?

Comment: @cmhughes: Yep, does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62791/messy-flowchart-using-tikz