# Node spacing based on node boundaries

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, nodes

> **TLDR:** Is there a way to get the nodes to space based on their 'tips'. Thus avoiding the `x-scale=#cm` all over the place to get things just right.

I am in the process of converting a bunch of visio diagrams to TikZ so I can version control them. One of the issues I am continually running into is node spacing. I usually write my code and then come up with something like this: (pre-paths)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, positioning}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{state}   = [ rounded rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=3em ]
\tikzstyle{test}    = [ diamond, draw, shape aspect=2, inner sep = 0pt, text width = 7em, text centered ]
\tikzstyle{action}  = [ rectangle, draw, text width=8em, inner sep = 5pt, minimum height=5em ]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, align = flush center, font = \small, xscale=5cm, on grid=true]
    % Place nodes
    \node [state] (a) {aLorem ipsum};
    \node [test, below of=a] (b) {bLorem ipsum dolor sit};
    \node [test, below of=b] (c) {cLorem ipsum dolor sit};
    \node [test, below of=c] (d) {dLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.};
    \node [action, below of=d] (e) {eLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas elementum,};
    \node [test, below of=e] (f) {fLorem ipsum dolor sit amet};
    \node [test, right of=f] (g) {gLorem ipsum dolor};
    \node [test, below of=f] (h) {hLorem ipsum dolo};
    \node [action, below of=h] (i) {iLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.};
    \node [action, right of=i] (j) {jLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.};
    \node [action, right of=j] (k) {kLorem ipsum dolor sit};
    \node [test, below of=i] (l) {lLorem ipsum dolor};
    \node [test, below of=j] (m) {mLorem ipsum dolor};
    \node [state, below of=l] (n) {nLorem ipsum};
    \node [state, below of=m] (o) {oLorem ipsum dol};
    \node [state, below right of=o] (p) {pLorem ipsum dolor sit \\ amet, consectetur}; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And it always ends up looking like garbage: [image: Garbage]

So I usually start playing around with `node distance` but that usually makes the chart run off the page and my vertical spacing usually can be tighter than my horizontal spacing. What I'm wondering is if there's a way to get the nodes to space based on their tips. Thus avoiding the `x-scale=1cm` all over the place to get things just right.

This is important, because I want it to be easy to edit in the future, so this layout has to be dynamic. If the API design changes and it's just some text addition, I don't want to have to spend 20min fiddling with `x-scale` to get looking nice.

I saw something here [drawing with a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62791/messy-flowchart-using-tikz) which looks promising, but it'd be a rewrite of work I've already done, so I don't want to invest more time to have it blow up in my face.

For reference, this is what I'm trying to replicate:[image: visio]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the `positioning` library's syntax: Instead of saying `right of=<node>`, you'll have to say `right=of <node>`. Also, in this case you'll want to use `on grid=false`. That way, the `node distance` refers to the distance between the edges of the nodes, not their centres:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, positioning}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{state}   = [ rounded rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=3em ]
\tikzstyle{test}    = [ diamond, draw, shape aspect=2, inner sep = 0pt, text width = 7em, text centered ]
\tikzstyle{action}  = [ rectangle, draw, text width=8em, inner sep = 5pt, minimum height=5em ]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2em, align = flush center, font = \small, on grid=false]
    % Place nodes
    \node [state] (a) {aLorem ipsum};
    \node [test, below=of a] (b) {bLorem ipsum dolor sit};
    \node [test, below=of b] (c) {cLorem ipsum dolor sit};
    \node [test, below=of c] (d) {dLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.};
    \node [action, below=of d] (e) {eLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas elementum,};
    \node [test, below=of e] (f) {fLorem ipsum dolor sit amet};
    \node [test, right=of f] (g) {gLorem ipsum dolor};
    \node [test, below=of f] (h) {hLorem ipsum dolo};
    \node [action, below=of h] (i) {iLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.};
    \node [action, right=of i] (j) {jLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.};
    \node [action, right=of j] (k) {kLorem ipsum dolor sit};
    \node [test, below=of i] (l) {lLorem ipsum dolor};
    \node [test, below=of j] (m) {mLorem ipsum dolor};
    \node [state, below=of l] (n) {nLorem ipsum};
    \node [state, below=of m] (o) {oLorem ipsum dol};
    \node [state, below right=of o] (p) {pLorem ipsum dolor sit \\ amet, consectetur}; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh wow. Can I get your address to send my firstborn? That's exactly the simple solution I was looking for.