# Can anyone help me out with this flowchart?

Tags: diagrams, conditionals, arrows, draw, flow-charts

[image]

Once again unable to understand the arrows. Can any one guide with example?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: There are many templates and posts in TSE like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62791/108724) that can help you.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified from my answer to your other question, a `pstricks` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}%

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\sffamily
\psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, shortput=nab}
\begin{psmatrix}[mnode = f, framesize=3.5 1.25, colsep=1cm, rowsep=1cm]
& [mnode=dia, name=D1]{\parbox[t][1.4cm]{1.4cm}{\mbox{}}}& [framesize=3.5 1.8, name=F3]\\
& [name=F1]\\
 [name=E, mnode=p] & [mnode=dia, name=D2]{\parbox[t][1cm]{1cm}{\mbox{}}}\\
 & [name=F2]
\end{psmatrix}
\psset{arm=1cm, angle=90}
\ncline{D1}{F1}^{Yes}\ncline{D1}{F3}^{No}\ncbar{F3}{D1}
\ncline{F1}{D2}
\ncline{D2}{F2}^{Yes}\ncline{D2}{E}_{No}
\ncangle[angleA=180, angleB=-90, arrows=-]{F2}{E}\ncangle{E}{D1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]