# Representing n-Nodes in Flow Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to do the following using Tikz code adapted from my previous [Question1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567307/adding-parenthesis-with-text-in-tikz-flow-chart) and [Question2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62791/messy-flowchart-using-tikz)
The code I am modifying credits to @Zarko:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric
                }
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
    node distance = 6mm and 15mm,
      start chain = A going below,
       arr/.style = {-Stealth},
every edge/.style = {draw, arr},
        BC/.style = {decorate,  % Brace Calligraphic
                     decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=3mm,
                                 raise=1mm, mirror},
                     very thick, pen colour={black}
                    },
       box/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!20, align=center,
                     minimum height=4em, text width=6em},
  decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.5, draw, fill=blue!20,
                    inner xsep=-3pt, text width=5.4em, align=center},
                        ]
 ellipse/.style = { ellipse, aspect=1.5,draw, fill=blue!20,
                    inner xsep=-3pt, text width=5.4em, align=center},
                        ]
% nodes
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A, join=by arr}]
\node   [ellipse]       {Initiate};     % name=A-1
\node   [box]       { Program Kernel};
\node   [box]  {Data Distribution};
\node   [box]       {Accept $S_{n+1}$};
\node   [box]       {$T_{n+1} = K(T_n)$ and $n=n+1$};
\node   [decision]  {Stop?};                            % A-6
    \end{scope}
% nodes in right column
\node   [box, right=of A-2] (rej) {Prior Data};
\node   [box, at={(A-6 -| rej)}] (stop) {Stop};
% edge labels and connections not considered in join macro
\path   

        (A-6)   edge ["yes"]  (stop);
\draw[arr]  (rej) -- node[auto]    {$D_1$} (A-2);
\draw[arr]  (A-6.west) to ["no" '] ++(-1,0) |- (A-2);
% braces
\draw[BC]   ([xshift=-12mm] A-1.north west) coordinate (aux) -- 
                    node[midway,left=5mm]{Stage 1}
            (aux |- A-4.south);
\draw[BC]   (aux |- A-5.north) --
                    node[midway,left=5mm]{Stage 2}
            (aux |- A-6.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I am unable to get the circle in the start despite adding ellipse in the styling and adding multiple nodes in horizontal with small circles showing n-blocks inbetween. The following is what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: :-), you give me credits for used code in your question, however you not accept my answer, where I propose it ;-).  You actually ask two question. The first is already solved by @Alenanno answer, the second request is to draw new image for you almost from scratch ...

Comment: @Zarko, i had accepted other answer even before you answered, I didnt know that I could change it. Since, I use your code so I gave you the credit :)

Comment: @Zarko The second part is where I am struggling, the three boxes for "Processor 1, Processor 2..Processor 3" are not coming up properly and I wanted to add three tiny dots between "Processor 1 and Processor 2" which needs spacing so im not sure how to do.

Comment: @Zarko done :) selected the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rude complete solution:

[image]

There exist more elegant code ...

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,
                fit,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric
                }
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    suspend join/.code = {\def\tikz@after@path{}}
        }
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
                
\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
    node distance = 3mm and 2mm,
      start chain = A going below,
       arr/.style = {-Stealth},
every edge/.style = {draw, arr},
        BC/.style = {decorate,  % Brace Calligraphic
                     decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm,
                                 raise=1mm, mirror},
                     very thick, pen colour={black}
                    },
       box/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!20, align=center,
                     minimum height=5ex, text width=#1},
box/.default = 5.5em,
  decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.5, draw, fill=blue!20,
                    inner xsep=-3pt, minimum width=5.4em, align=center},
    ellip/.style = { ellipse, aspect=1.5,draw, fill=blue!20,
                    inner xsep=-3pt, text width=5.4em, align=center},
                        ]
% nodes in chain
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A, join=by arr}]
\node   [ellip]     {Initiate};         % name=A-1
\node   [box]       {Program Kernel};
\node   [box]       {Data Distribution};
\node   [suspend join, 
         font=\bfseries,
         below=12mm]    {\dots};        % A-4
    \end{scope}
% nodes in the left column
\node   [box=4em, left=of A-4] (p2) {Procesor 2};
\node   [box=4em, left=of p2]  (p1) {Procesor 1};
% nodes in the right column
\node   [box=4em, right=of A-4] (pn) {Procesor $n$};
% nodes in the main column
\node   [box, fit=(p1) (pn),
         below right=8mm and 0mm of p1.south west,
         label=center:Main server] (ms) {};
\node   [decision, below=of A-4 |- ms.south]    (ptc) 
                               {Packet Transfer\\ Complete?};
% nodes in the left
\node   [box=4em, at={(p1 |- A-2)}] (ld)  {Load Data};
\node   [box, at={(p1 |- ptc)}]  (stop) {Continue};
% edge labels and connections not considered in join macro
\draw[arr]  (ld)   to["$D_1$"]     (A-2);
    \foreach \i in {p1, p2, pn}
{
\draw[arr] (A-3) -- (\i);
\draw[arr] (\i) -- (\i |- ms.north);
}
\draw[arr]  (ms.south -| ptc)   to  (ptc);
\draw[arr]  (ptc)   to["no" ']        (stop);
\draw[arr]  (ptc.east) to ["yes"] ++(1,0) |- (A-2);
% braces
\draw[BC]   (p1.north west) --
                    node[left=3mm]{Stage 2}
            (p1.south west);
\draw[BC]   (p1.west |- ld.north) --
                    node[left=3mm]{Stage 1}
            (A-3.south -| ms.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Its not rude solution! Its exactly what I wanted! The only thing is that the arrow on the right connecting "packet transfer to program kernel" is out of the page, its going out of view

Comment: @gfdsal, I use default page layout defined by `scrartcl` document class and there is not out of text area, it is nice centered in it. Similar result I obtain at `article` document class. How you include this image in your document?

Comment: you not mentioned, that your document has two columns and that your image you like have in one column ... see edited answer (aap)

Comment: Sorry, i haven't installed `ieeeconf` document class. If it have different page layout as `ieeetran` than possible solution is to use `figure*` without positioning options instead of `figure` .  Than figure will occupy both column but it will appear on the top of the next page.

Comment: It works AMAZING! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not advisable to name the style *exactly* as the name of the shape, TikZ will not be able to distinguish between the two. So you should change `ellipse` to something else, as this name already identifies the shape itself.

Your issue is easily solved by moving the style out of the `tikzpicture` options and into a `\tikzset` like so:

```
\tikzset{
    elli/.style={ellipse, aspect=1.5,draw, fill=blue!20,
                    inner xsep=-3pt, text width=5.4em, align=center},
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Alright, and how do you suggest to produce the n-nodes part, the one shown in stage 2 parenthesis? I am actually too close but this is only stopping me

Comment: @gfdsal Do you mean the little blue circles?

Comment: yes the three blocks in parallel and the three little blue circles.