# Calligraphic braces in equation environment

Tags: equations, brackets

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  a(y)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    0 & \text{if}\ y < 1 \\
    \frac{1}{2}\biggl[ 1 + sin\left(\frac{2 \pi}{\theta}\right) \biggr]  & \text{if}\ 1\leq y < 4 \\
    1 & \text{if}\ 4 \leq y < 5 \\
 \frac{1}{2}\biggl[ 1 - sin\left(\frac{2 \pi}{\theta}\right) \biggr]  & \text{if}\ 6 \leq y < 7 \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

How to achieve the following calligraphic curly brace (The following image borrowed from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567342)) offered by TikZ package, in equation environment:

[image]

A similar style was implemented for a matrix in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67841046). I couldn't implement it for an equation.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use upright `sin` and smaller square brackets first?

Comment: There are almost almost 10 rows. This is the simplified version of the code.

Comment: I think @PrzemysławScherwentke was suggesting to reduce the vertical size of the square brackets (at least for the given example - can't say for your actual use case), and also to use `\sin` instead of `sin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that there is an elegant solution using the `nicematrix` package, but I haven't the experience of that to provide it.  Here's a tikz solution that wraps the array environment in a tikz node and then decorates the left-hand edge with a brace.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/627983/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a(y)= \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(base)]
\node (array) {\(\displaystyle\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}} 0 & \text{if}\ y < 1 \\
\frac{1}{2}\biggl[ 1 + \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi}{\theta}\right) \biggr] & \text{if}\ 1\leq y < 4 \\
1 & \text{if}\ 4 \leq y < 5 \\
\frac{1}{2}\biggl[ 1 - \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi}{\theta}\right) \biggr] & \text{if}\ 6 \leq y < 7 \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{array}\)};
\path (array) +(0,-.5ex) coordinate (base);
\draw[decorate, decoration=calligraphic brace,ultra thick] (array.south west) -- (array.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: equation with calligraphic brace]

Obviously, there are parameters to tweak to improve the look, such as line width and amplitude.

(Incidentally, this is exactly the use-case I was envisioning when I designed these braces.)

Here's with `amplitude=3mm`:

[image: with a larger amplitude]

Comment: Looking at the question you linked to, I see that Zarko uses `amplitude=3mm`, and I think that looks good here too.

Comment: @ Andrew Stacey, can you please tell where to include the `amplitude=3mm` in the code? I don't see it.

Comment: `decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=3mm}`

Answer (score 4):

I would focus on making the expression more compact, mainly by replacing the `\frac` notation with "slash" notation (aka inline fraction notation). And, since you're loading the `mathtools` package, you could use its `cases*` environment instead of a plain `array` environment.

Oh, and by all means, do write `\sin`, not `sin`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'cases*' environment

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  a(y)=
  \begin{cases*}
    0                                     & if $\hphantom{1\leq{}}y < 1$ \\
    \frac{1}{2}[ 1 + \sin(2\pi/\theta) ]  & if $1 \leq y < 4$ \\
    1                                     & if $4 \leq y < 5$ \\
    \frac{1}{2}[ 1 - \sin(2\pi/\theta) ]  & if $6 \leq y < 7$ \\
    0                                     & otherwise
  \end{cases*}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment: To generate a truly elegan tall curly brace, you could [download](https://pctex.com/) and install the `mtpro2` package -- note that while the full package isn't free of charge, its 'lite' subset is free -- and use its `\ccases` macro. The elegant curly brace can be up to 10 cm (4 inches) tall. Observe that the `mtpro2` math fonts are in the Times Roman family of fonts; this may or may not be to your liking.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}      % for '\text' macro
\usepackage{newtxtext}    % Times Roman clone text font
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % for '\ccases' macro

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  a(y)=
  \ccases{
    0                                     & \text{ if $\phantom{1\leq{}}y < 1$} \\
    \frac{1}{2}[ 1 + \sin(2\pi/\theta) ]  & \text{ if $1 \leq y < 4$} \\
    1                                     & \text{ if $4 \leq y < 5$} \\
    \frac{1}{2}[ 1 - \sin(2\pi/\theta) ]  & \text{ if $6 \leq y < 7$} \\
    0                                     & \text{otherwise}
  }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that calligraphy braces by TikZ package looks more elegant than the default LaTeX style. Furthermore, as the number of rows increases the default LaTeX style looses elegance.

Comment: @Aim - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Thanks for the edit!

Comment: You are Always welcome ️️