# My tikzpicture is to large for my beamer frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm extremely new to LaTeX and this is my first post on this site. I have a major presentation coming in a couple weeks, and I'm in great need of your help.

I export Geogebra code for my graphs, it's much easier for me as an amateur. Well, it's too big for the frame. I've tried everything I can find on this site, and nothing seems to work.

Here's my code for the frame:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Why do we care about the area under the curve?} 
    \definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0.75}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
        \draw [color=cqcqcq,dash pattern=on 320pt off 320pt, xstep=0.5cm,ystep=200.0cm] (-0.82,-100) grid (2.18,1100);
        \draw[->,color=black] (-0.82,0) -- (2.18,0);
        \foreach \x in {-0.5,0.5,1,1.5,2}
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
        \draw[->,color=black] (0,-100) -- (0,1100);
        \foreach \y in {,200,400,600,800,1000}
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
        \draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
        \clip(-0.82,-100) rectangle (2.18,1100);
        \draw[line width=1.2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.0:2.181034482758621] plot(\x,{915});
        \draw (0.06,1066.88) node[anchor=north west] {Figher Jets at supersonic speed starts at 915 miles per hour.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you looked at the `scale` key for a `tikzpicture`, i.e. in your case using something like `scale=.8` in the `{}` begind the `\begin{tikzpicture}` ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that from looking at another post, and for some reason it still won't work? Maybe I'm typing it wrong?

Comment: I don't know, whether you typed it wrong, I didn't ;) Anyways, maybe this might also help: [Scaling a tikzpicture for a Beamer slide](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62788/scaling-a-tikzpicture-for-a-beamer-slide)

Comment: If I turn your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and added the `arrows` library, I still get `Dimension too large` errors which means that the TikZ picture not only fits on a `beamer` frame but also not on any paper size producible with TeX. The last `\draw` alone is over 10 metres out. Using `x=3cm,y=.005cm` brings back the picture in a way one can actually read the content. You should use the `pgfplots` package if you deal with a) such big numbers and b) plots.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP reports it's fixed, and it looks likely this is a 'trivial' fix.
 