# TikZ picture to fit beamer page

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am trying to put `tikzpicture` in `beamer`.
Currently, I am creating it in a separate PDF file in `article` mode and then crop it; because I have no idea how I can scale the `tikzpicture` to fit my `beamer` window.

I am here putting a complete real `flowchart`, that I want to use directly in beamer. Any help will be useful.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill={rgb:red,3;green,39;blue,233}, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=4cm, inner sep=0pt, text=white, font=\bfseries]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill={rgb:red,3;green,39;blue,233}, 
    text width=8em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em, node distance=2cm,
  text=white, font=\bfseries]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex', line width=2pt]
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill={rgb:red,0;green,114;blue,255}, node distance=4cm,
text width=5em, text centered, minimum height=2em, text=white, font=\bfseries]

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    \node [block] (init) {initialize model};
    \node [cloud, left of=init] (expert) {$V^{(2)}_{ij}$ from \textit{ab initio} DFT};
    \node [cloud, right of=init] (system) {lattice structure};
    \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {identify models (Ising/ Heisenberg)};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (mc) {Monte Carlo};
    \node [block, below of=mc] (evaluate) {Metropolis Alogorithm};
    \node [block, left of=evaluate, node distance=4cm] (iteration) {Iterate};
    \node [decision, below of=evaluate, node distance=3cm] (decide) {System Converged?};
    \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {Evaluate $T_c$, magnetization,    correlation  \textit{etc.}};
    \node [cloud, right of=evaluate](how) {choose $V^{(2)}_{ij}$ according to shell and local concentration};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (mc);
    \path [line] (mc) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node {\large\textbf{yes}}(stop);
    \path [line,dashed] (expert) -- (init);
    \path [line,dashed] (system) -- (init);
    \path [line] (decide) -| node [near start] {\large\textbf{no}} (iteration);
    \path [line] (iteration) |- (mc);
    \path [line,dashed] (how) -- (evaluate);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try adding options `transform shape,scale=.6` to the `tikzpicture` environment. But looks like your *long* picture is not going to fit well with a *wide* Beamer frame.

Comment: BTW, regarding your use of `\tikzstyle` take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles.

Comment: A suggestion, you could try letting the flowchart grow horizontally. That way, the picture will fit the Beamer frame a lot better, and nicer.

Comment: The issue has been analyzed several times here; have a look to [Scaling a tikzpicture for a Beamer slide](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62788/13304) and [Scaling tikz mindmaps within a beamer frame](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78202/13304).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\scalebox`. The result is not beautiful, but the final scaling and positioning is left to you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill={rgb:red,3;green,39;blue,233}, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=4cm, inner sep=0pt, text=white, font=\bfseries]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill={rgb:red,3;green,39;blue,233}, 
    text width=8em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em, node distance=2cm,
  text=white, font=\bfseries]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex', line width=2pt]
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill={rgb:red,0;green,114;blue,255}, node distance=4cm,
text width=5em, text centered, minimum height=2em, text=white, font=\bfseries]


\scalebox{0.5}{ % PS
 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    \node [block] (init) {initialize model};
    \node [cloud, left of=init] (expert) {$V^{(2)}_{ij}$ from \textit{ab initio} DFT};
    \node [cloud, right of=init] (system) {lattice structure};
    \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {identify models (Ising/ Heisenberg)};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (mc) {Monte Carlo};
    \node [block, below of=mc] (evaluate) {Metropolis Alogorithm};
    \node [block, left of=evaluate, node distance=4cm] (iteration) {Iterate};
    \node [decision, below of=evaluate, node distance=3cm] (decide) {System Converged?};
    \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {Evaluate $T_c$, magnetization,    correlation  \textit{etc.}};
    \node [cloud, right of=evaluate](how) {choose $V^{(2)}_{ij}$ according to shell and local concentration};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (mc);
    \path [line] (mc) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node {\large\textbf{yes}}(stop);
    \path [line,dashed] (expert) -- (init);
    \path [line,dashed] (system) -- (init);
    \path [line] (decide) -| node [near start] {\large\textbf{no}} (iteration);
    \path [line] (iteration) |- (mc);
    \path [line,dashed] (how) -- (evaluate);
\end{tikzpicture}   
} % PS
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does `auto ` do in node distance?