# How to scale a tikzpicture in an external file for a beamer slide?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, scaling, standalone

I have this tikz diagram in a separate document. I use the `standalone` package to include it into my presentation. However, I experience several problems:

- Setting the included picture size
- Scaling the picture so that it matches the visible frame area exactly
- Placing the picture in an arbitrary position within the file

For concreteness here is my main document

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{inflines theme}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{infolines theme}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
 \hbox{%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}%
   \end{beamercolorbox}%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.75\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}%
   \end{beamercolorbox}%
 }%
}%

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{infolines theme}{\relax
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\relax
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}\frametitle{Frame Title}
       \include{mindmap}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

While the included tikzpicture, residing in a file named `mindmap.tex`, is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
  \begin{scope}
 [
 every node/.style={concept,circular drop shadow,execute at begin node=\hskip0pt},
 text=white,
 root concept/.append style={
   concept color=black, fill=black, line width=1ex, text=white, font=\large\scshape
 },
 grow cyclic,
level 1/.append style={level distance=4.5cm,sibling angle=51.5,font=\itshape},
level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45,font=\bf\scriptsize}
]
  \node at (0,100) [fill=white, line width=1ex, text=black,font=\large\scshape] {Introduction to Programming Languages} [clockwise from=0] 
     child [concept color=gray] { node {Administration} [clockwise from=75]
        child {node {Office Hours} }
        child {node {Course Material} }
        child {node {Exams} }
        child {node {Assignments} }
     }  
     child [concept color=purple, sibling angle=33] { node {Hello, World!} } 
     child [concept color=green!50!black, sibling angle=33] { node {Syntactical Elements} 
         [clockwise from=-10]   
     child { node {Identifiers} 
           [clockwise from=0]
           child { node {Autarkic} 
             child { node {Pre-Declared Identifiers} }
           }
           child [sibling angle=60]{ node {Library Based} }
         }
     child { node {Literals} 
           [clockwise from=-60]
           child { node {String Literals} 
              [clockwise from=0]
              child { node{Escaping} } 
           }
         }
     child { node {Keywords} }
     child { node {Comments} }
     child { node {Blocks} }
     } 
     child [concept color=red!30,text=black, sibling angle=46] { node {Specification} [scale=2,clockwise from = -90]
       child {node {Semantics}
       [clockwise from = -45]
     child { node {Recursively Defined Sets} }
     child [sibling angle=60] { node {Language Legalese} }
     child [sibling angle=60] { node {Formal Semantics} }
       } 
       child[sibling angle=90] {node {Syntax} 
       [clockwise from = 210]
    child {node {RegExp}}
    child [sibling angle=45] {node {BNF}}
    child [sibling angle=45] {node {EBNF}}
      }  
    }
    child [concept color=yellow!40, text=black,sibling angle=45] { node {Motivation} }
    child [concept color=teal,sibling angle=53] { node {Paradigms} [clockwise from=45]
    [clockwise from = -150]      
      child { node {Imperative} }
      child [sibling angle=60] { node {Functional} }
      child [sibling angle=60]{ node {Logical} }
      child [sibling angle=60] { node {OO}}
    }
    child [concept color=orange] { node {History} } 
 ;
 \end{scope}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

The output I get is quite annoying:

[image: The presentation with the included tikzpicture]

BTW, I read this question, [Scaling a tikzpicture for a Beamer slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62788/scaling-a-tikzpicture-for-a-beamer-slide), and it does not seem to shed light into this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}` outside the preamble. To include the mindmap with a specified width just use

```
\includestandalone[width=.75\linewidth]{mindmap}
```

The preamble of the included files can be used if package option `subpreambles` is set to `true`.

You might like to replace the `\documentclass{article}` with `\documentclass{standalone}`, if you only draw an image.

*Please try to create a MWE. There was no real reason for all the formatting in the main document and the big tree*

Your code could look like this:

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{inflines theme}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{infolines theme}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
 \hbox{%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}%
   \end{beamercolorbox}%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.75\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}%
   \end{beamercolorbox}%
 }%
}%

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{infolines theme}{\relax
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\relax
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}\frametitle{Frame Title}
       \centering
       \includestandalone[width=.75\linewidth]{mindmap}

   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**mindmap.tex:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
  \begin{scope}
 [
 every node/.style={concept,circular drop shadow,execute at begin node=\hskip0pt},
 text=white,
 root concept/.append style={
   concept color=black, fill=black, line width=1ex, text=white, font=\large\scshape
 },
 grow cyclic,
level 1/.append style={level distance=4.5cm,sibling angle=51.5,font=\itshape},
level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45,font=\bf\scriptsize}
]
  \node at (0,100) [fill=white, line width=1ex, text=black,font=\large\scshape] {Introduction to Programming Languages} [clockwise from=0] 
     child [concept color=gray] { node {Administration} [clockwise from=75]
        child {node {Office Hours} }
        child {node {Course Material} }
        child {node {Exams} }
        child {node {Assignments} }
     }  
     child [concept color=purple, sibling angle=33] { node {Hello, World!} } 
     child [concept color=green!50!black, sibling angle=33] { node {Syntactical Elements} 
         [clockwise from=-10]   
     child { node {Identifiers} 
           [clockwise from=0]
           child { node {Autarkic} 
             child { node {Pre-Declared Identifiers} }
           }
           child [sibling angle=60]{ node {Library Based} }
         }
     child { node {Literals} 
           [clockwise from=-60]
           child { node {String Literals} 
              [clockwise from=0]
              child { node{Escaping} } 
           }
         }
     child { node {Keywords} }
     child { node {Comments} }
     child { node {Blocks} }
     } 
     child [concept color=red!30,text=black, sibling angle=46] { node {Specification} [scale=2,clockwise from = -90]
       child {node {Semantics}
       [clockwise from = -45]
     child { node {Recursively Defined Sets} }
     child [sibling angle=60] { node {Language Legalese} }
     child [sibling angle=60] { node {Formal Semantics} }
       } 
       child[sibling angle=90] {node {Syntax} 
       [clockwise from = 210]
    child {node {RegExp}}
    child [sibling angle=45] {node {BNF}}
    child [sibling angle=45] {node {EBNF}}
      }  
    }
    child [concept color=yellow!40, text=black,sibling angle=45] { node {Motivation} }
    child [concept color=teal,sibling angle=53] { node {Paradigms} [clockwise from=45]
    [clockwise from = -150]      
      child { node {Imperative} }
      child [sibling angle=60] { node {Functional} }
      child [sibling angle=60]{ node {Logical} }
      child [sibling angle=60] { node {OO}}
    }
    child [concept color=orange] { node {History} } 
 ;
 \end{scope}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image: result]