# Need help in beamer mind maps

Tags: beamer, mindmaps

Can anyone help me fit my mind map in beamer?

**EDIT:**

I have these codes for the figure, but how I would like to fit the figure in beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{comment}
:Title: Computer science mindmap
:Tags: Manual, Mindmap

Version 1.09 of PGF/TikZ added a library for drawing mindmaps. Here's an example
from the manual. 

| Author: Till Tantau
| Source: The PGF/TikZ manual

\end{comment}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] {Unit Root Tests}
    [clockwise from=15]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {Granger Causality (TY p.)}
      [clockwise from=90]
      child { node[concept] {Full Sample}}
      child { node[concept] {Pre and Post Sample}}
    }  
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {Cointegration Test}
      [clockwise from=-30]
      child { node[concept] {Full Sample} }
      child { node[concept] {Pre and Post Sample} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {Break Point Tests} [clockwise from=-90] 
        child { node[concept] {ZA and PPU Tests}}}
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {Classical Tests} [clockwise from=90] 
        child { node[concept] {ADF, PP, and KPSS Tests}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this

[image]

Comment: I'm no TikZ mind map expert, but it doesn't look like you've tried to draw any mind map whatsoever.  Why haven't you at least tried to draw a simple example from the manual or maybe one of the ones from the [mind map examples](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/mindmaps/) on http://texample.net ..?

Comment: I've tried those but they're not working in Share Latex's beamer.

Comment: @ogc they should work. What problem did you run into?

Comment: Well, 'they're not working in X' is a difficult thing to help with, not least because you never mentioned that part. But it is also hard to know what is not working or why it is not: presumably you are getting a (set of) specific error(s), not an error that says 'you cannot use mind maps on Share LaTeX'....

Comment: It gives a page of errors. Can you help with the outline of codes. I tried some codes from online before and it looked complicated.

Comment: Tried those mate but to no avail.

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.85, small mindmap, every mindmap/.append style={font=\tiny}, every concept/.append style={font=\tiny}]`. But I really shouldn't be answering this since i almost never use TikZ....

Comment: @OGC "It gives a page of errors" happens, but normally only the first error is relevant - start with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to shrink a `tikzpicture` to fit inside a beamer frame, see, e.g., [Scaling a tikzpicture for a Beamer slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62788/scaling-a-tikzpicture-for-a-beamer-slide).

One possibility using `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={.9\textwidth}{.7\textheight},center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] {Unit Root Tests}
    [clockwise from=15]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {Granger Causality (TY p.)}
      [clockwise from=90]
      child { node[concept] {Full Sample}}
      child { node[concept] {Pre and Post Sample}}
    }  
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {Cointegration Test}
      [clockwise from=-30]
      child { node[concept] {Full Sample} }
      child { node[concept] {Pre and Post Sample} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {Break Point Tests} [clockwise from=-90] 
        child { node[concept] {ZA and PPU Tests}}}
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {Classical Tests} [clockwise from=90] 
        child { node[concept] {ADF, PP, and KPSS Tests}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Making a mind map is not, strictly speaking, a beamer capability, but is (for example) a tikz capability.  I have never tried to put a tikz mind map on a beamer slide, but the coding would start with using some tikz code.  I am not sure if there are other LaTeX-based implementations of mind maps, but tikz includes "mindmap" in its extensive library, and would be a natural way to solve your problem.  Cheers

Comment: Yes, seems like you may be right as so far I've failed in incorporating the tikz codes in beamer. they just don't run.